# Data exchange between workspaces without promouting

Tags: version-control, accurev

I have a couple workspaces under my stream on Accurev 5.7.

How to properly exchange modified files/data between workspaces that placed under same stream without promoting action to the parent stream.

Would be helpful both UI and command line actions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In workspace1 -> Keep foo.c

In workspace2 -> select foo.c -> Right Click -> History -> Browse version -> Select version you kept in workspace1 -> Right click -> Choose either "Send to Workspace", "Patch From" or "Merge From"

The CLI equivelent, see commands, co, patch and merge.